# ros::param::getCached will not update and gives errors

Tags: ros, parameter, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can't seem to make full use of ros::param::getCached....while I CAN retrieve a value that is set on rosmaster, I get this error continuously:

```
[DEBUG] [1479155346.850264931]: XML-RPC call [subscribeParam] returned an error (-1): [ERROR: parameter [caller_api] is not an XMLRPC URI]

[DEBUG] [1479155346.850767245]: Subscribe to parameter [/boob]: call to the master failed
```

This message comes from some python validator on the roscore side I think...and there my debugging ability will fail me.

Can I get some insight into what might be going on?  My `ROS_MASTER_URI` is not remarkable and my general ROS nodes operate correctly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248093/ros::param::getcached-will-not-update-and-gives-errors/) by [codenotes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20029/codenotes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 261 on 2016-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would add that doing some subsequent research, these errors happen and I fail when using:

ros::param::getCached()

however:

somenodehandle.getParamCached()  DOES seem to work.

so I think maybe the docs should specify that ros::param::getCached() is probably not to be used.   If you want updated parameters, one needs to go through a valid nodehandle.

---

Originally posted by [codenotes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20029/codenotes/) with karma: 261 on 2016-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-15**:
Hm. If you feel this is a bug or an oversight, you could report this to the `ros_comm` [issue tracker](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues).